# MySQL rebuild after Corrupt ibdata1

Tags: mysql, mysql5

I have a MySQL server that serves a couple of databases including a Magento e-commerce store.

We have been suffering with corruption in the ibdata1 file for a while, but it has now reached a critical point.

The only database that uses innodb tables is the Magento webstore back-end.

I have an up to date SQL extract of the entire magento database. I thought that I could shut down MySQL, rename the ib* files, restart MySQL and re-create the database from the SQL file - however I am having a major problem restarting MySQL after renaming the ib* files.

I keep getting 'cannot connect to mysql ..... mysql.sock'.

It appears as though the ib* files are all re-created as I would expect, but I can't restart and then connect to the sever...

Any ideas??

Comment: Have you checked the mysql.err (mysql logfile)? I think you'll find more info there. As InnoDB in fact does not support repairs I still would have a look on the innodb_force_recovery option.

Comment: Yeah - there is plenty in the log file about it being 'difficult to find free blocks from the buffer pool'. Have also tried all values of innodb_force_recovery up to and including 6... no dice. The corrupt ibdata came to light when I was unable to drop a database from the server - produced mySQL errors. Investigation into this issue let me to the corrupt file. Server now crashes every few minutes and cannot be recovered apart from recoursing to complete server backup restore... Am potentially facing a complete rebuild on this box